# Changing SPARQL query with the jQuery attr() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sparql, sgvizler

I'm working on a semantic web application and I'm using Sgvizler. I'm not using a database, fuseki, php or something like that. I would like to let the user select certain value and use that value in a SPARQL query. The user can select a value from a drop down menu and then click the search button to return that value. I'm using the jQuery attr() method to change the data-sgvizler-query attribute into the desired query. I got this code so far:

```
<body>
<form>
<select id="values">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="searchbutton" value="Search"/>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchbutton").click(function(){
        $("#sgvzl_example").attr("data-sgvizler-query","SELECT * WHERE {myprefix:" + $('#values').val() + " ?b ?c}");       

});
});

$(document).ready(sgvizler.containerDrawAll);
</script>

<div id="sgvzl_example"
data-sgvizler-query="SELECT * WHERE { myprefix:1 ?b ?c}"
data-sgvizler-chart="google.visualization.Table"
data-sgvizler-log="2"
style="width:800px; height:600px;"
></div>

</body>
```

Unfortunately this is not working. The data-sgvizler-query attribute won't change. I made sure all my prefixes, sparql endpoint etc. are correct. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Is this related to your earlier question, [User selected variables in SPARQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26515603/1281433)?  I haven't look close enough to see if they're duplicates, but they seem related.  If you made progress on the earlier question, be sure to post and accept an answer to it.  After all, Stack Overflow is about helping *everyone* who has similar questions.